# how to re-install portainer docker?

Tags: docker, ubuntu, portainer

I made a site with docker very long time ago but I lost the password of portainer. So, I try to re-install to reset my Id and password, but it seems portainer keep containing my previous Id and password. I delete volume but is still not working.
I did like this.

step1. stop and delete container.

```
$sudo docker ps -a (to check container list)
$sudo docker stop [container ID]
$docker rm -v [container ID]
```

step2. delete image

```
$docker images (to check image ID)
$docker rmi [image ID]
```

step3. delete volume

```
$docker volume rm portainer_data
```

step4. re-install portainer

```
$docker run -d -p 9000:9000 --name portainer --restart always -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock -v/data/portainer/data:/data portainer/portainer
```

when I try to access to portainer, still asking last ID and password.

Answer (score 0):

It's likely this is browser/cache related. Can you try running in incognito mode and see if the issue is present there.

If that resolves it then clear your cache out.

Answer (score 0):

I made the same mistake.  Like you, I had set the bind mount and didn't notice it in the command.  According to your start command, it looks like you set your bind mount storage to `/data/portainer/data`.

So to re-install, you can: stop portainer, delete `/data/portainer/data` to clear the data, then start the container back up.

Alternatively, portainer does have a [method](https://documentation.portainer.io/v2.0/users/reset-admin/) to reset only the admin password.